Using deduction guide for array of pairs
Suppose I want to make an array of pairs:
std::array my_pairs{
    std::pair{1.23, 1},
    std::pair{3.14, 2},
    std::pair{7.89, 3},
};

In different instantiations, the first type in the pairs will differ, and the number of elements will differ, but the second type in the pairs will remain the same.
Is there a way to use a deduction guide to avoid the need to write std::pair for each element?
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
using PairArray = std::array<std::pair<T, int>, size>;

// magic code goes here

PairArray my_pairs{
    {1.23, 1},
    {3.14, 2},
    {7.89, 3},
};

Alternatively, could a helper function be defined to make it work?
template</* ??? */>
auto make_pair_array(/* ??? */) { /* ??? */ }

auto my_pairs = make_pair_array(
    {1.23, 1},
    {3.14, 2},
    {7.89, 3}
);


use C++20 std::to_array: auto my_pairs = std::to_array<std::pair<double, int>>({ {1.23, 1}, {3.14, 2}, {7.89, 3}});

https://godbolt.org/z/T1YcEab6E

It doesn't help with this case but if the type has an initializer list constructor like std::vector you only need to specify the inner type once: std::vector my_pairs{std::pair{1.23, 1}, {3.14, 2}, {7.89, 3}};

How to pass variadic amount of std::pair with different 2nd types to a function

@user12002570 That duplicate target is incorrect. It's about deduction of a list of pairs where the pairs can be of different types. In this question, the types of all the pairs in any given list is the same.

@cigien The problem is the same. The template parameter cannot be deduced in both cases. That is, in both cases(if the pairs are different or same), both are not allowed to use deduction(which is the basic problem the program fails). I've added another dupe: Passing multiple std::pair to variadic template constructor using { }, { }

"It's about deduction of a list of pairs where the pairs can be of different types...." No, it's fundamentally about "deduction" only. The problem is with the deduction part not with pair having different types.  Basically, we have a non-deduced context. Even std::pair isn't relevant here. You could just use any other type like std::vector<T> etc where T won't be deduced because of deduction cannot happen(non-deduced context). The same problem will exist even if we pass pairs of same types. This clearly shows it doesn't have to do with different type pairs but with "deduction" failure.

@cigien To be clear: there are now two duplicate targets. The second one seems like a correct match and gives a solution.
